# Why does Auth0 store my application's user data?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, auth0

[image]
I have an auth0 app . After every login , user information is available on  [Users](https://manage.auth0.com/#/users)

- Where is this data stored?
- Does auth0 persist all of this?
- Can i disable this.

My assumption is that Auth0 talks to a Social connection like Google or Facebook and does not need to store this information. This is a tenancy issue and some clients don't like their data to be available on a third party server in some cases.

Can anyone validate my concern?

Comment: I think you should contact the company with your concerns I dont think SO can answer this question for you.

Comment: yea, i am already waiting on that . Just wanted to get some heads up quickly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *We do persist a limited amount of data for all Users, and that cannot be disabled. Clicking on the user to see their details you can see whats stored for social connections. The data is stored on Auth0's infrastructure for customers using either our multi-tenant or dedicated cloud Deployment Models. We do offer the ability for you to provide your own cloud infrastructure as well as on-premises installations if you have physical security requirements. You might also be interested in reviewing our Security and Compliance documents.*

- Matt Maddex
  Technical Support Engineer for Auth0

That helped me out.